# ado.net MVC3 way of ADO.NET using

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

which way is used for ADO.NET MVC3 data entering

**1**

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\\Courier.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd;
conn.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("Exec InsertCountry @Name =" + country.Name, conn);                
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Or

**2**

```
private CEntities db = new CEntities();
db.Countries.AddObject(country);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you restate?

Comment: through which code statment i use ado.net entity frame work

Comment: If you're looking for Entity Framework, number 2 is the way to go.

Comment: Number 1 is classical 'pure' ADO.Net. Number 2 is ADO.Net Entity Framework, also called Entity Framework for short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way can work for working with data in ASP.NET MVC. The first one is using ADO.NET straight up, using sql commands and what not. The second one looks like it's possibly using Entity Framework or Linq to SQL.

If you're working an existing data access layer, you're probably going to be doing things the first way. If you're lucky enough to start a brand new project, you would probably want to take advantage of the much cleaner way using Entity Framework of Linq to SQL.

Once again, both are acceptable way of working with data in MVC projects.

As reference for using ASP.NET MVC with an existing data access layer which is not Entity Framework or Linq to SQL, you can read the article, [ASP.NET MVC is not all about Linq to SQL](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/132/ASP.NET-MVC-is-not-all-about-Linq-to-SQL), where an exiting N-Layer application built with WebForms and ADO.NET is upgraded to an MVC project with no real changes made to the way the data is returned.

Good luck, and hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 is classical, 'pure' [ADO.Net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET).

Number 2 is [ADO.Net Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework), also called Entity Framework for short, which adds an Object/Relational Mapper (ORM) on top of classical ADO.Net.